# IE ignoring jQuery .val()

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I have the following bit of jQuery for adding a "clear" button to the end of a search form:-

```
$('#search-tools input:last').after($('<input>',{
  'class': 'search-clear'
  , 'val': 'Clear'
  , 'type': 'submit'
  , 'click': function() {
    // do something
  }
}));
```

This works well in all browsers except IE; in IE the input button is not getting the value "Clear" set and instead displays "Submit query". Am I setting val incorrectly or is this a known IE issue with jQuery?

Comment: `val` is not an attribute, it is a jQuery method that sets the value of an input element. The actual attribute is called `value`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know you could add attributes to a newly-created DOM element this way.

Comment: @lolwut ... doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/b8mk6/1/

Comment: I've tried 'value': 'Clear' but still get 'Submit Query'. Really confused by this one as I am sure I've had similar code working before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out...
You have to define the `'value'` property *after* the `'type'` property:

```
$('<input>', {
    'class': 'search-clear',
    'type': 'submit',
    'value': 'Clear',
    'click': function() {
        // do something
    }
})
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/b8mk6/10/

---

IE *clears* the value of the `'value'` property when the `'type'` property is set to `'submit'`. So:

```
var input = document.createElement( 'input' );

input.value = 'test...';
input.type = 'submit'; // the value is cleared

document.body.appendChild( input );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Z3xQ5/1/

Comment: Thanks. That works great. It seems a little strange that the order of the attributes would matter in IE!

Comment: +1. I realize that this works, but you may still want to be careful with setting the `type` attribute that way, as the jQuery documentation indicates it's not supported in IE: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '<input>', {
    'class':'search-clear',
     'type': 'submit',
    'click': function () {}
}).appendTo( 'body' );
$('.search-clear').attr('Value','Clear');
```

this works for some reason

Comment: But that doesn't mean that jQuery couldn't accept `"val"` as a shorthand, too. Which it does apparently, since both `"value"` and `"val"` work (except IE, where neither one works).

Comment: Check my code, works in JSFiddle, though I dont see why, probably one of IE's good old bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the `type` of the input element. Try to set it to `button` instead of `submit` if you don't want this to behave like a submit button, it works very well. Try this.

```
$( '<input />', {
    'class': 'search-clear',
    'value': 'Clear',
    'type': 'button',
    'click': function () {}
}).appendTo( 'body' );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8mk6/11/